# Find the portion of code that defines a built-in Python function's name

Tags: python

I've been trying to search the source code of CPython for the names of various built-in functions. What I'm interested in is locating the lines that define the names of these functions, what the Python interpreter's "look-up" procedure looks at when it encounters a function. If I change these lines, then I should be able to change the names of the functions, too.

In this case, I tried searching for the `abs` function in the C source code files on the GitHub page for CPython. [This](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?l=c&q=abs&utf8=%E2%9C%93) is the link to the search query I was using. There are 30 results, but none of them contains a string like `"abs"` or anything like that aside from what looks like strings for documentation.

How would I go about finding these particular lines of code?

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*, here?

Comment: This search result from `Python/clinic/bltinmodule.c.h` looks like the starting place: `#define BUILTIN_ABS_METHODDEF    \
     {"abs", (PyCFunction)builtin_abs, METH_O, builtin_abs__doc__},`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Learning how interpreters work.

Comment: Then I think something that takes a [ten-hour video series](http://pgbovine.net/cpython-internals.htm) is too broad to cover on SO.

Comment: Put the code down and step away slowly, no Python functionality needs to die here today.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the part of the search results that specifies the association between the name `abs` and the function that implements it.

```
Python/clinic/bltinmodule.c.h 
Showing the top six matches. Last indexed on Oct 1, 2015.

11  #define BUILTIN_ABS_METHODDEF    \
12      {"abs", (PyCFunction)builtin_abs, METH_O, builtin_abs__doc__},
```

If you go to `bltinmodule.c.h` you'll find similar definitions for all the built-in Python methods.

Comment: Could this be extended to looking for things like the methods associated with various built-in classes like strings and numbers?

Comment: There's probably similar types of macros for them.